# Magento migrate products, categories and users

Tags: migration

I got a simple (?) recommendation question about migration part of DB.

There's an old website we have which is in Magento 1.7. The problem with it is that it has long and colorful history behind it and it's time for it to go. The biggest issue was that it had a lot of custom changes and big step from 1.4-1.7 which didn't go that well. But it's now up and running and it's doing fine :) But fine is not enough so we're moving on.

We have a new Magento 1.8 website ready to go. The development is finished and we need to feed it with... Well, after long discussion we decided not to go ahead with orders and start from the scratch BUT migrate all products (around 1k) with categories and images AND users (~12k) with user data but not orders.

**QUESTION:**
What would be the best recommendation to do that? Do you have any plugin suggestion or should we go with development team to do it manually DB->DB (they quoted quite a lot of money to migrate and I mean a lot!). Also does anyone have any experience with this: http://www.shopping-cart-migration.com/ and can tell me how it works and is it safe/worth it?

Thanks in advance guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used cart 2 cart quite a lot, and 99% of the time, it's pretty good. It's probably the most simple solution for you if you have a limited knowledge.

The other option (if you're comfortable with the command line) is using magerun. You can use some of the key features to strip out on customer and orders and then import them in to your fresh database -

https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun#stripped-database-dump

Let us know how you get on.

James